# How to "inherit" UNIQUE property?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

So, my problem is that I have a table, called `"USER"`, in my database, and another table `"STUDENT"` inheriting from it, plus some more specific fields.

Creating `"USER"` looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "USER"
(
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  login    CHARACTER VARYING(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password CHARACTER VARYING(32)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pass',
  name     TEXT                         NOT NULL,
  email    TEXT,
  role     CHARACTER VARYING(32)        NOT NULL
);
```

Creating `"STUDENT"` looks, for example, like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "STUDENT"
(
  state TEXT,
  hire_date DATE,
  english_level TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT student_login_key UNIQUE(login)
) INHERITS ("USER");
ALTER TABLE "STUDENT" ALTER COLUMN role SET DEFAULT 'stud';
```

The problem is that column `login`, which should be unique, is actually unique in both of these tables separately, but not unique "together". I mean, if I add a row into table `"USER"` with `login` 'temp', and then add a row into "STUDENT" with the same `login`, I'll get two rows in my table "USER" with the same logins "temp" and no error.

On the other hand, column `id`, which is autoincrement, works great: in has a single 'sequence' for both of the tables.

What should I do to save the unique property in 'union' of tables "USER" & "STUDENT"?

Comment: Aside: stay away from double-quoted upper-case identifiers in Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately.  The documentation even mentions this as a [significant limitation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) with table inheritance.

You might want to just have two independent tables, and give `student` a unique foreign key to `user`.